# How to associate object with its type

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a statistics system in C++ which will allow me to associate a string with a value of an arbitrary type. Currently, I have it working with an `enum` that keeps track of the type and a `void *` that points to the object, but this requires me to make individual `if` statements for all of the types I want to support. I'd like to have it so that I can support any arbitrary type using some kind of template. I've created some test code that sort of works, but there are issues:

```
class Test {
    std::type_index type;
    void *value;

public:
    template <typename T>
    Test(T val) : type(typeid(val)) {
        T *val_p = new T;
        *val_p = val;
        value = (void *)val;
    }

    Test() : type(typeid(void)) {
        value = nullptr;
    }

    ~Test() {
        //no idea how I could make this work
    }

    template <typename T>
    T get() {
        if (std::type_index(typeid(T)) == type) {
            T *val_p = (T *)value;
            return *val_p;
        } else {
            throw std::bad_typeid();
        }
    }
};
```

What I have so far works, but I don't think it would be possible to implement a destructor or copy/move constructors. The whole point is I want to store this all in a single `std::unordered_map`, so I can't (AFAIK) just make a template class and go from there. So, is it possible to do what I'm trying to do, and if so, how would I do it?

Comment: If you can narrow down those arbitrary types, a `union` may be useful to you.

Comment: It looks like you need boost::variant.

Comment: Looks like you're looking for `boost::any`. Usually you really want a variant though (`boost::variant`).

Comment: Actually, one other thought is that you *might* be able to create an abstract base class that serves as the type for the map, and then a templated derived class.

Comment: As an association of a String with the address of an arbitrary value is easy, what you exactly need to do afterwards ? I mean you want e.g. to print something that has to do with the value ( so you will need it's type ) or what. Essentially if the system is static you may use some kind of template, but if the system is dynamic ( I mean you are able to create a value and associate it while the program is running) than a dynamic approach is needed.

Comment: In case a dynamic approach is needed, than I suggest to limit your self to values that are class instances ( avoiding built in types). In that case, for any such value you may define in it's class the behaviour that you need for an action and have it done by calling a virtual method related to the class the instance belongs.

Comment: All of these are decent approaches, but a lot of them are not very easily expandable (i.e. little to no extra code to add another type). I'm going to go with `boost::any`, since it will do what I want it to do. Thanks for all of the suggestions though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the suggestion of [GManNickG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87234/gmannickg), I'm going with `boost::any`, as it most closely resembles what I'm looking for.

I haven't yet implemented it into the code, but the basic structure will be something along the lines of:

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <boost/any.hpp>

class Statistic {
    boost::any value;

public:
    template <typename T>
    Statistic(T val) : value(val) {}

    Statistic() : value() {}

    template <typename T>
    bool checkType() {
        return typeid(T) == value.type();
    }

    //Will cause an exception if the type doesn't match
    //Caller should check type if unsure
    template <typename T>
    T get() {
        if (checkType<T>()) {
            return boost::any_cast<T>(value);
        } else {
            //throw some exception
            throw bad_any_cast();
        }
    }
}
```

With this, I don't need to deal with destructors or copy/move functions, since the implicit ones will call the code already implemented by the boost library.

EDIT:
Thanks to [milleniumbug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012936/milleniumbug) for pointing out `boost::any` already stores the `std::type_info`

Comment: Recommend padding this out a bit with your eventual solution to turn this answer into something that can help people with the same problem in the future. Right now this answer is basically dangling downvote bait.

Comment: Notice that `boost::any` already stores the `std::type_info` for you (see `.type()`)

Comment: Ah thanks. I was doing that to make exceptions less needed, but that is easier